# Why are words becoming highlighted in white in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

See the below image. Why are words becoming highlighted in white when I start editing them?
It used to start happening randomly, where re-opening VS would solve the issue. However, now it seems to persist, making it impossible to write any code as the words are unreadable..

As soon as I type a letter, the word that's being edited gets highlighted like in the image below.

Why is this happening and how do I stop it from happening?

[image: Text being highlighted in white]

Comment: If those are "inline hints" then you can "Press Ctrl twice to toggle inline hints".

Comment: No, that's not it sadly. With "inline hints" disabled in options, the issue persists.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, I can't find the checkbox in the "Options" UI that is called, "Disable all really annoying new features."

Comment: Do you have any custom color configurations?

Comment: No, I haven't made any changed to settings or anything like that